# Boost numpy linker error in Windows VS

Tags: python, visual-studio, numpy, boost

I am using Boost 1.64 with visual studio to create a module for python. Specifically, I am using the Boost Numpy module to be able to work with numpy arrays in the module.

I have compiled Boost with the following command:

```
b2 -j8  address-model=32  --user-config=D:\code\libraries\boost_1_64_0\user-config.jam --with-python   --build-type=complete stage --stagedir=stage/win32
```

In my code I have added the static link defines (which seems to be needed from all the posts I have read) : #define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB

Two odd things happen when I compile my code:

1) when using the diagnostics define (#define BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC) it shows the compiler linking to the STATIC version of the python library, but linking to the dynamic version of numpy library:

- Linking to lib file: libboost_python-vc141-mt-1_64.lib
- Linking to lib file: boost_numpy-vc141-mt-1_64.lib

When i disable auto linking and just add the right libraries myself, I end up getting an unresolved linker error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::python::numpy::dtype __cdecl boost::python::numpy::detail::get_float_dtype<32>(void)" (??$get_float_dtype@$0CA@@detail@numpy@python@boost@@YA?AVdtype@123@XZ)
```

The odd thing is that this error is only thrown on the usage of functions in numpy that use templates! I can actually run code that uses boost_numpy library that dont use template functions and it will link and run fine! 
Does anyone know why are the template based functions throwing this linker error?
Any help is much appreciated!

H

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the linker error by adding:

```
#define BOOST_NUMPY_STATIC_LIB
```

So my preamble is now:

1. `#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB`
2. `#define BOOST_NUMPY_STATIC_LIB`

and the error goes away.

H

Comment: Thanks for this, you've saved me a fair bit of time.